# Split 2d array from every row add it to new rows pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` which look like this,

```
A   B
1   [[1], [2]]
2   [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
3   [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

I want to convert this to follwing `dataframe`.

```
A   C     D
1   1     2
2   1     3
2   2     4
3   1     6
3   2     7
3   3     8
3   4     9
```

Is there any clean way for this transformation?

So far I have written this code.

```
import pandas as pd
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.tolist(), index= df.index, columns=["C", "D"])
# this is the output
A   C            D
1   [1]          [2]
2   [1, 2]       [3, 4]
3   [1, 2, 3, 4] [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Thank you

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```py
A = [l[0] for l in df["B"]]
B = [l[1] for l in df["B"]]
A = [A[i][:len(B[i])] for i in range(len(A))]

A2 = []
C = []
D = []
idx = 1
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        A2.append(idx)
        C.append(x)
        D.append(y)
    idx += 1

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": A2, "C": C, "D": D})
```

Output:

```
    A   C   D
0   1   1   2
1   2   1   3
2   2   2   4
3   3   1   6
4   3   2   7
5   3   3   8
6   3   4   9
```

Answer (score 0):

You provide inconcistent data in the question.  In the first part the nested lists are of unequal lenghts, whereas the alternate example after your edit *does* have nested lists of equal lengths.

My solution below assumes the latter, i.e. the nested lists are of equal lengths.

```
# generate data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 2, 3],
    "B": [
        [[1], [2]],
        [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
        [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
    ]})

# create new columns C & D
df = pd.concat([df.A, df.B.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df.columns = ['A', 'C', 'D']
```

Output:

```
   A             C             D
0  1           [1]           [2]
1  2        [1, 2]        [3, 4]
2  3  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Now explode the nested lists.

```
col_a, col_c, col_d = [], [], []
lens = df.D.agg(len).to_list()

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    col_a.extend([df.A.iloc[i]] * lens[i])

for i in df.C:
    col_c.extend(i)

for i in df.D:
    col_d.extend(i)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": col_a, "C": col_c, "D": col_d})
```

Output:

```
   A  C  D
0  1  1  2
1  2  1  3
2  2  2  4
3  3  1  6
4  3  2  7
5  3  3  8
6  3  4  9
```